# How Hexadecimal and Octal counts in Coding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, numbers, octal

`print(0o15)` it's output is `13` but i am getting confuse how it's working. and `print(0xFB + 0b10)` it's output is `253` please let me know with example, how it's working.

Comment: `print(0o15)` should be printing 13, not 15.

Comment: Sorry for mistake, it's printing 13 but how??

Comment: It is printing the result in decimal.  15 (octal) = 13 (decimal).  Likewise 0xFB (hex) = 251 (decimal) and 0b10 (binary) = 2 (decimal).  251 + 2 = 253 (decimal)

Comment: Because in octal 15 is one *eight* and five ones. This isn't really a programming issue, read up on what the base/radix of a number means.

Answer (score -1):

The octal digits are 0-7. The decimal digits are 0-9.

In octal, after 7 (the last digit) we get 10. Which is still 8 (in decimal).

Keep counting up and you'll see.